# Perform query in django against another table, but its not finding the table

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to perform a query via a [join](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

My models.py looks like:

```
class TSFH(models.Model):
sB = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
sE = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
FKToUser = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Tld(models.Model):
dNm = models.CharField(verbose_name="",max_length=40,unique=True)
FKToUser = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class TSF(models.Model):
FKToT = models.ForeignKey('T', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
FKToTSFH = models.ForeignKey('TSFH', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
enteredd = request.GET.get('d', '')
query=TSFH.objects.filter(FKToT__dNm=enteredd,FKToUser=request.user,sE__isnull=False)
return render(request, 'view.html', {'q':q})
```

**templates/file.html**

```
{% if q %}
{% for res in q %}
<li><span>{{ res.sE }}</span></li>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

When I view this all it complains about:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'FKToT' into field
```

In plain sql I'm looking to perform the following just with `dNm` search directly from the `enteredd` instead of a hardcoded value of `123.145.23.1` as shown below:

```
SELECT sE 
FROM tsfh, tsf, t
where 
tsfh.id=tsf.FKTotsfh_id
and
t.id=tsf.FKToT_id
and
tsfh.sE is not null
and 
t.dNm='123.145.23.1';
```

How can I keep these existing checks in the `query` but include this `FKToT__dNm=enteredd` somehow?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You filter on the `TSFH`, that model has no `FKToT`, only the `TSF` has.

Comment: I understand that, im having issues formulating how i could rewrite this to garner what i'm after here. can you so graciously help @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I assume `t` is your `tld` table, and thus the foreign key to `'T'` is in reality `'Tld'`?

Comment: What about `TSF.objects.filter(TSF__FKToT__dnm='123.145.23.1', sE__isnull=False)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - this is invalid. `TSF` has no corresponding `FKToT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a little modification at this line:

```
query=TSFH.objects.filter(TST__FKToT__dNm=......)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put this meta into your class, it will specifically name the table.

```
class Meta:
    db_table = '<your_table_name>'
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/).